# r.green error installation on GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0, grass.script, rgrass7

I am using GRASS GIS 7.0.3 on linux, however I've been trying to install the r.green extension on GRASS and always get the error message:

"ImportError: cannot import name set_path"

"WARNING: libgreen and libhydro not in the python path"

The repository is: https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7

I have been using GRASS for several years and never had any issues on installing extensions before.

I have little to zero knowledge on python but based on the error message, I suppose there is a missing scripts on the repository?

Is there anyone else here experiencing similar issues? or had managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider to update to [GRASS GIS 7.8](https://grass.osgeo.org/download/) (your installation 7.0.0 is very old), not only for relevant updates including the change to Python 3, but also to follow our infrastructure migration from SVN to git (GitHub). The improved `r.green` addon has been moved here:

Software: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/tree/master/grass7/raster/r.green

Manual: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.green.html

The extension manager of a recent GRASS GIS installation reflects all these improvements.